# error C2065: 'cp' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c, arrays, string, visual-studio-2010

I am a new to C, I found this tutorial about string and arrays on the internet, and tried to do the program. They are using eclipse and I am using Visual Studio 2010...please help and explain.
I am getting these problems:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'type'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
error C2065: 'cp' : undeclared identifier
error C2100: illegal indirection
warning C4552: '!=' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
error C2065: 'cp' : undeclared identifier
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
error C2065: 'cp' : undeclared identifier
error C2100: illegal indirection
```

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


int main(char argc, char**argv){
    char s[] = "string";
    printf("string is: %s\n", s);

    for(char *cp = s; *cp !=0; ++cp) {
        printf("char is %c\n", *cp);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: vs2012 is happy with this :)

Comment: Side note: change `char argc` to `int argc`.

Comment: @gongzhitaao what compiler does it have?

Comment: @Perception it won't work

Comment: @eLg this is my ``cl.exe`` version: ``Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.51106.1 for x86``

Comment: @gongzhitaao how will I know my [cl.exe version] ?

Comment: @eLg Open ``Developer Command Prompt for VS2010`` and type ``cl --version``

Comment: Methinks you're running with a C89 compiler. inline-decls like the for-loop are not allowed.

Comment: Not sure why this is closed as "too localized". It should be a duplicate of this: [Declare c89 local variables in the beginning of the scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9513604)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft's C compiler only implements the C90 standards (plus a few extensions). It does not have full support for the newer C99 or C11 standards. See (and vote for!) [this bug report on MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/485416/support-c99) to encourage them to add support for modern C. [This blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/11/05/iso-c-standard-update.aspx) from the compiler team also contains some relevant information.

The upshot, though, is that you cannot declare variables in the initialization of a `for` loop. In fact, the only place you can declare variables is at the very top of a block.

If you move the declaration of `cp` to the top of the method block, it will compile just fine.

```
int main(char argc, char**argv){
    char s[] = "string";
    char *cp = s;//move to here

    printf("string is: %s\n", s);        

    for(; *cp !=0; ++cp) {
        printf("char is %c\n", *cp);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;// you should return some value
}
```

Alternatively, you can introduce a new block scope in the body of your function.

Comment: Actually, it does since C99. And nowadays, C is C11 already.

Comment: The Microsoft C compiler however, only supports c89 (and a few extensions)

Comment: @Zoidberg sorry. My mistake, but seems the problem is caused by this syntax. Maybe his compiler does not support this syntax.

Comment: @nos yes, strandards is nice, reality however is suffering..hah

Comment: @zoujyjs I tried to do that,but it won't work

Comment: MS doesn't support *either* declarations in for loop headers *or* mixed declarations and statements. Move the declaration of `cp` above the `printf`, and it should be ok. (And it would be more idiomatic to do the initial assignment to `cp` in the for loop header: `char *cp; ... for (cp = s; *cp != '\0'; ++cp)`)

Comment: @eLg move `char *cp = s` up to the `printf`

Comment: @KeithThompson exactly！

Comment: MS will never support C99 or C11 either. because a lot of microsoft's internal code and windows itself relies on c89

Comment: @KeithThompson and others who commented thank you.It's working now.

Comment: @Aniket That's unlikely to be the explanation. I can't think of very many things that worked in C89 but would break if they added C99 support to the compiler. You'd just get a lot of support for new things, like variable declarations anywhere in the body of a function, and variable length arrays. The reason they give for not supporting C99 (or C11 for that matter) is that there's not enough consumer request. They claim not enough of their customers are using C anymore to justify it. Note that the C++ compiler does support lots of these things and will compile *most* C code.

Comment: @CodyGray `register int restrict = 0;` compiles on C89, and fails on C99. Now imagine a few hundred or thousand like that in the whole windows code base. I agree with your comment..99%